# Get three values from one string in python

Tags: python, string, integer

I'm currently coding in python, but i have a problem;
I have a string called data, and three integers (a, b, c).

```
data = "{1,2,3}"
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
```

I want to get the numbers from the data variable, and place them into a, b, c like this:

```
data = "{1,2,3}"
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

How would i do that?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: It's standard practice at Stackoverflow that you first try to code yourself. Only when you run into problems you ask for help.

Comment: If you don't try, the chances that someone else will are really slim.

Comment: *"i have not tried anything, please dont ask me for code. there is nothing to share"* - then please come back when that's no longer true. http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: writing a oneliner in 10 seconds to answer an okay question is not gonna hurt anybody, that said. Writing 200 lines of code for the OP's homework is something else.

Answer (score 2):

`{1,2,3}` is valid Python code.  Unfortunately, when evaluated it gives you a `set` which has no order.  Evaluate string `'{1,2,3}'` and we could end up with `{3,1,2}`.  But we can switch out those curly brackets for parenthesis and we get `(1,2,3)` which is a `tuple`!  Tuples keep their order.  And even better we can unpack them via assignment:

```
>>> import ast
>>> data = "{1,2,3}"
>>> data = data.replace('{','(').replace('}',')') # make it look like a tuple
>>> data_as_tuple = ast.literal_eval(data) # safe "eval".  don't do: eval(data)  
>>> a, b, c =  data_as_tuple # unpack tuple via assignment
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

Note:  You may not need variable names `a`,  `b`, and `c`.  What if you need to bring in ten numbers instead of three?  Do you need to then write in seven more variable names?  If `a`, `b`, and `c` all represent the same type of thing you may be better off leaving them as a `tuple` or `list`.  Then you can have one name for the collection and not worry about giving names to each item in the collection.  Then if you need to take action on the items you use iteration:

```
for item in data_as_tuple:
    print(item*3) # or whatever
```

**To the downvoters:**

Beginners often lack the lingo to use when searching for answers.  What do you search for if you don't know that breaking text into parts is called splitting a string?  If you've never heard of regular expressions how would you stumble across an answer using that?  If you didn't know that text can be evaluated as code how would you get to `ast.literal_eval`?

Further, it seems the OP doesn't yet think in collections, just variable-name => value.  If the OP wanted to extract the data into a list his code would be more robust because he could handle different size collections.

Anyway, it's hard to tackle all these issues.  If the question is very simple I toss the OP a bone.  I assume that motivated students will gather up concepts as they encounter them.

Personally, I draw the line at answering homework problems that show no effort.  What's different about those problems is that there are nearly always multiple subproblems the OP can attempt to solve.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! :DD

Comment: Please don't encourage this, This is in the question: `(i have not tried anything, idk how to do it, pls dont ask for code)`

Comment: Hmm... downvoters what's up?

Comment: Oh, I see.  If you want to lose 2 points to be the Stack Overlow police knock yourself out.  **Bring it on!**

Comment: don't worry about this. It's all about not writing code for others...

Comment: I think OP didn't posted his efforts and still you answered it.

Comment: efforts? if the question is good, we don't care about efforts: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338755/whats-better-a-question-with-no-attempt-or-with-an-unfixable-irrelevant-attemp

Comment: @DineshPundkar:  That's important to you.  It wasn't all that important to me.  Perhaps you can go downvote some of my other answers too.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski you have 26K points. A few downvotes won't hurt you at all. But Karol needs to learn for him/her self also. Pointing him to a link of how ast works or string replacement works would have helped more (in my view).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski that's random your answer (and mine) is okay, but the OP pissed everyone off with his question, and we pay for that :)

Comment: Wow this is good question !!! on top of that OP clearly saying  I didn't put effort or tried anything. he didn't even google it.

Comment: @VikashSingh:  Yeah, I didn't get around to fleshing out my answer before the downvotes started pouring in.  Now I'm just going to leave it and wear it like a badge of honor.  Jean-François Fabre's answer was most excellent with regard to explanation and the pitfalls of the two approaches he presented.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Sorry man.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski maybe we should edit OP question and add crap code that has no chance to work and the question will suddenly become good. Not providing code is not a problem if the question is good enough.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre agreed with you, but this `(i have not tried anything, idk how to do it, pls dont ask for code)` was part of the question when we started this discussion. It's not anymore so I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @VikashSingh wanna see a bad question with some code? look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423515/parsing-a-list-using-multiple-lists-python. If the question pisses you off only by its wording and not technical content (urgent/help/my sister has cancer, etc...), edit it, close it, downvote it, but don't take it on the okay answers.

Comment: another bad one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423603/how-to-shuffle-questions-in-python. Will never get 5 downvotes, while it deserves 10.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Steven Rumbalski you can go through my answers and find ton of times I have helped beginners, but those question are nicely put, and are not rude to others. Here the case was different. Anyways, we are here to help people so I will move on from this thread. Will see you guys around :)

Comment: @VikashSingh no problem. Opinions differ. See you.

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of ways to do it. Here are 2 of them:

Using `ast.literal_eval`, but replacing curly braces by brackets or order isn't guaranteed, unpack in `a,b,c`:

```
import ast

data = "{1,2,3}"

a,b,c = ast.literal_eval(data.replace("{","[").replace("}","]"))

print(a,b,c)
```

with `re.findall` followed with integer conversion. Only extracts numbers, doesn't care about delims.

```
import re

a,b,c = (int(x) for x in re.findall(r"\d+",data))

print(a,b,c)
```

of course, both approaches are very fragile. Should there be 2, or 4 items, you get a "value unpack" exception.

Comment: Thanks! That helped!

Comment: I like `re.findall` solution best.  And good job noting the fragility of the approaches.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches you can use. Given the format of the data you described, I would recommend the following steps:

1. Remove the extraneous braces (`{}`)
2. Split the string into it's comma-separated pieces.
3. Convert those pieces to numbers.

You can do this in one line of python:

```
>>> [int(x) for x in '{1,2,3}'[1:-1].split(',')]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Or break it down into steps:

```
>>> s = '{1,2,3}'
>>> s = s[1:-1]
>>> ss = s.split(',')
>>> xs = [int(s) for s in ss]
>>> print(xs)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Hope that helps.