# how to shuffle questions in python

Tags: python

please anyone help me i have posted my whole work down can anyone tell me how to shuffle theses five questions it please i will be very thankful.

```
print("welcome to the quiz")
Validation = False

while Validation ==False:

    name=input("Please enter your name")
    age=int(input("Please enter your age"))
    print("Use keboard to play the quiz")
    play=input("Are you ready for the online safety questions")
    if play.capitalize()== "Yes":
        if age >16:
            print("This quiz might be easier for you")

        print("welcome to the quiz")
        Validation = False)

        question1=input("Q1:What is CEOP?/A:Child Exploitation and Online Protection/B:Child Exploitation and Organised Protectors/C:Criminal Exploration and Online Protection")
        score = 0
        if question1.capitalize() == "A":
            print("WELL DONE")
            score = score + 5
        elif question1.capitalize() =="B":
            print("Wrong Answer")
        elif question1.capitalize() =="C":
            print("Wrong Answer")
        else:
            print("Wrong Answer")
        print("so far, you have",score,"marks")

        question2=input("Q2:When you get an email from someone you do not know, what should you do?/A:Reply and say hello/B:Delete it and mark as spam/C:Forward to your friends")
        if question2.capitalize() == "B":
            print("WELL DONE")
            score = score + 10
        elif question2.capitalize() =="A":
            print("Wrong Answer")
        elif question2.capitalize() =="C":
            print("Wrong Answer")
        else:
            print("Wrong Answer")
        print("so far, you have",score,"marks")

        question3=input("Q3:How secret should you keep your passwords?/A:Give them to strangers/B:Give them only to your best friends/C:Never give out passwords except to your parents")
        if question3.capitalize() == "C":
            print("WELL DONE")
            score = score + 15
        elif question3.capitalize() =="B":
            print("Wrong Answer")
        elif question3.capitalize() =="A":
            print("Wrong Answer")
        else:
            print("Wrong Answer")
        print("so far, you have",score,"marks")

        question4=input("Q4:When an online contact who frightens you asks to meet you in person what should you do?/A:Arrange to meet them with your best friend/B:Arrange to meet them/C:Report to CEOP")
        if question4.capitalize() == "C":
            print("WELL DONE")
            score = score + 20
        elif question4.capitalize() =="B":
            print("Wrong Answer")
        elif question4.capitalize() =="A":
            print("Wrong Answer")
        else:
            print("Wrong Answer")
        print("so far, you have",score,"marks")

        question5=input("Q5:If an email asks you to enter your bank account details because of a problem with your account what should you do?/A:Reply to the email/B:Contact the bank to check if they sent the email/C:Enter your bank account details")
        if question5.capitalize() == "B":
            print("WELL DONE")
            score = score + 25
        elif question5.capitalize() =="C":
            print("Wrong Answer")
        elif question5.capitalize() =="A":
            print("Wrong Answer")
        else:
            print("Wrong Answer")    

        print ("Thank you for doing the quiz", name,".You scored", score, "marks in the quiz")
        Validator=True
    else:
        Validation=False
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't shuffle them the way they are hard-coded. Store the questions is a list, and use the [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function on that list. You could do something like

```
validation = False
while validation ==False:
    # input age
    if age > 16:
       validation = False

    questions = [
       ('question 1 text', 'A'),
       ('question 2 text', 'C')...]

    random.shuffle(questions)

    for question_text, correct_answer in questions:
        user_input = input(question_text)

        if user_input.capitalize() == correct_answer:
           score += 5
           print("well done")
        else:
           print("wrong answer")

    validation = True
```

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Comment: still confused as this our coarse work we need to use while loop or functions to do it and also need to use validations.

Comment: questions = [
       ('question 1 text', 'A'),
       ('question 2 text', 'C')...]

    random.shuffle(questions)

    for question_text, correct_answer in questions:
        user_input = input(question_text)

        if user_input.capitalize() == correct_answer:
           score += 5
           print("well done")
        else:
           print("wrong answer")                                                               iam just confused in this part can you explain this.

Comment: You just store question-answer pairs in a list and use a for loop. The rest is the same as your code.

Answer (score 0):

First make a list (or a dict) with your questions and answers:

```
Q = [
    "What is CEOP?", #Each question and answer is defined by a number this one is 0
    "When you get an email from someone you do not know, what should you do?", #This one is 1
    "How secret should you keep your passwords?", # 2
    "When an online contact who frightens you asks to meet you in person what should you do?", #And so on
    "If an email asks you to enter your bank account details because of a problem with your account what should you do?"
    ]

A = [
    "A:Child Exploitation and Online Protection/B:Child Exploitation and Organised Protectors/C:Criminal Exploration and Online Protection",
    "A:Reply and say hello/B:Delete it and mark as spam/C:Forward to your friends",
    "A:Give them to strangers/B:Give them only to your best friends/C:Never give out passwords except to your parents",
    "A:Arrange to meet them with your best friend/B:Arrange to meet them/C:Report to CEOP",
    "A:Reply to the email/B:Contact the bank to check if they sent the email/C:Enter your bank account details",
    ]
```

Define a list to keep track of the shown questions:

```
QAsked = []
```

Make a definition for selecting a question:

```
def SearchQ():
QProposed = random.randint(0,4)
    if QProposed in QAsked: #If already asked
        SearchQ()           #Search again
    else:
        QAsked.append(QProposed)
        print(Question: Q[QProposed])
        print(Answer: A[QProposed])
        CheckIfOK(QProposed)
```

Remember to `from random import randint`.

`CheckIfOK(Question)` is something like:

```
if Question == 1:
    ans = input("Answer: ")
    if ans.capitalize() == "A":
        print("WELL DONE")
        score = score + 25
    elif ans.capitalize() =="B":
        print("Wrong Answer")
    elif ans.capitalize() =="C":
        print("Wrong Answer")
    else:
        print("That's not an answer")
if Question == 2:
    ans = input("Answer: ")
    if ans.capitalize() == "C":
        print("WELL DONE")
        score = score + 25
    elif ans.capitalize() =="B":
        print("Wrong Answer")
    elif ans.capitalize() =="A":
        print("Wrong Answer")
    else:
        print("That's not an answer")
...
```